# How to use PUT method in Laravel API with File Upload

Tags: laravel, api, put

Having read this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089221/what-is-the-difference-between-put-post-and-patch),

`PUT` is most-often utilized for update capabilities, PUT-ing to a known resource URI with the request body containing the newly-updated representation of the original resource.

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711235/10907303),

> ... we need to send ***all*** the parameters of the data again.

In my controller, I have:

```
$student = Student::find($student_id);
$student->username = $request->username;
$student->email = $request->email;
$student->password = $request->password;
$path = $request->file('passport')->store('upload');
$student->passport = $path;
```

I have once used this same code for `POST` method and it worked, but while using it for APIs, I used POSTMAN `form-data` and got `$request->all()` to be `null`. Some said I should use `x-www-form-urlencoded` but this does not allow files upload.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is actually an [incapability of PHP itself](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815). A PUT/PATCH request with `multipart/form-data` just **will not** populate `$_FILES`, so Laravel has nothing to work with.

Every once in a while, people report bugs [like this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457) when they find `$request->all()` returns null, thinking it's Laravel's fault, but Laravel can't help it.

Files are best sent as `multipart/form-data` and that sort of request will **only** populate `$_FILES` if it's a **POST**. No `$_FILES`, no `$request->file()`.

In lieu of having this work as-expected in PHP, if it works using a POST, just use a POST.

Comment: Wish I had known this before. Wracked my brain on this for more than a day.

Answer (score 9):

When the form contains uploaded file it works only with POST method - probably an issue with PHP/Laravel

If someone wants to use a PUT or PATCH request for form containing file uploads

```html
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')

    ...
</form>
```

via any javascript framework like vue

```js
let data = new FormData;
data.append("_method", "PUT")

axios.post("some/url", data)
```

Using `_method` and setting it to 'PUT' or 'PATCH' will allow to declare route as a PUT route and still use POST request to submit form data

I have answered a similar question [How to update image with PUT method in Laravel REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887893/how-to-update-image-with-put-method-in-laravel-rest-api/64888199#64888199)

Comment: Thats usefull :) tx