# Can we use PUT method for file upload in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

API Route

```
Route::post('user/profile', 'ApiUserController@updateProfile');
```

Dump in controller

```
dd($request->all());
```

Output: (working fine with POST method)

```
array:2 [
  "nick_name" => "steven"
  "avatar" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1387
    -test: false
    -originalName: "P3-Info2.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpIID1sL"
    basename: "phpIID1sL"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpIID1sL"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpIID1sL"
    aTime: 2021-03-14 16:50:42
    mTime: 2021-03-14 16:50:42
    cTime: 2021-03-14 16:50:42
    inode: 7874635
    size: 82806
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 33
    group: 33
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

If I change the request method to `PUT`, the output is empty as follows.

```
[]
```

May I know how to send the file with `PUT` method?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65009135/10573560

Comment: have you include `@method('PUT')` in your HTML `form`?