# Laravel resource update with upload file

Tags: php, laravel

I create a resource for `NewProgram` model, it works for READ, CREATE AND DELETE, but not for UPDATE, the problem is there is a file need to update too, here's my `store` function for example

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $program = new NewProgram;
    $program->name = $request->name ?? '';
    $program->description = $request->description ?? '';
    $program->date_from = $request->date_from ?? '';
    $program->date_to = $request->date_to ?? '';
    $program->location = $request->location ?? '';
    $program->organizer = $request->organizer ?? '';

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $attachment = $this->uploadAttachment($request->file('image'));
        $program->image_url = route('image', $attachment->uuid);
    }

    $program->save();
    return response()->json($program);
}
```

Yup, that's for `store` function and it works perfectly using postman, but here's the problem, I can update the data from NewProgram, but not for the file because the `update` function only receives a request from `x-www-form-urlencoded` not like `store` that receive from `form-data`, here's my code

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $program = NewProgram::find($id);

    $program->name = $request->name ?? '';
    $program->description = $request->description ?? '';
    $program->date_from = $request->date_from ?? '';
    $program->date_to = $request->date_to ?? '';
    $program->location = $request->location ?? '';
    $program->organizer = $request->organizer ?? '';
    $program->image_url = $request->image_url ?? '';
    $program->save();
    return response()->json($program);
}
```

here's screenshot from postman

[image: postman]

How to fix this? I want to make `update` function also update the file/attachment, not the string

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a duplicate, there is a reason you can't use form-data on put requests, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65008650/how-to-use-put-method-in-laravel-api-with-file-upload)

but using x-www-form-urlencoded doesn't make it better

Just use post with form-data as some answers for the question in the link I gave suggest